# Keep getting an error. Code: "CS1524" Description: "Expected catch or finally"

Tags: c#, try-catch

Here is the snippet of code I'm getting the error from:

```
try
{
    rec.RequestRecognizerUpdate();
    rec.LoadGrammar(gr);
    rec.SpeechRecognized += rec_SpeechReccognised;
    rec.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
    rec.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
}
```

The last bracket is where it says the error is. Re-typed and checked over code but for the life of me I can't find anything wrong with it...

Comment: It expects a `catch` or `finally`. Whats the `try` supposed to do?

Comment: The error message is pretty self explanatory and even a cursory glance at the docs would give you the answer here.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs1524

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have just try. You need to add a either a finally or catch (or both) to get the code to compile.

Comment: Although in truth, `try finally` has lessened since `using {}` blocks took over from explicit `Dispose()`

Answer (score 3):

Read the error message. It says you need a `catch` or `finally` block. Add one.

For example,

```
try
{
    rec.RequestRecognizerUpdate();
    rec.LoadGrammar(gr);
    rec.SpeechRecognized += rec_SpeechReccognised;
    rec.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
    rec.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Logger.Log(ex);
}
```

If you literally don't care about the exception, just "swallow" it:

```
try
{
    ...stuff...
}
catch (Exception)
{
    ...gulp...
}
```

Keep in mind that swallowing exceptions is a bad practice.